# Firebase function with no specific Content-Type returns undefined rawBody

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm integrating with a 3rd party service that calls our URL.
Unfortunately, they don't set `Content-Type` header in their requests.
Apparently, firebase functions returns `undefined` rawBody if there's no Content-Type set.
Is there any way to work around this?

Here's my function code:

```
const cors = require("cors")({
  origin: true,
});

export const hookHandler = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => {
    return cors(request, response, () => {
      if (request.rawBody === undefined) {
        response.status(200).send({ error: "undefined body" });
      } else {
        response.status(200).send({});
      }
    });
  }
);
```

__

Doesn't work:

`curl https://us-central1....statusHook -d '{"dupa":1}' -H "Content-Type:"`

Works fine:

`curl https://us-central1....statusHook -d '{"dupa":1}' -H "Content-Type:application/json"`

Comment: This is probably not the answer you're looking for, but you might have to convert this into an Express app, and use some body-parsing middleware to collect the body content as it arrives, and make an assumption about what you want to do with it, without the help of a content type.

Comment: I agree with @DougStevenson on using a body-parsing middleware, I couldn't find any reference online or documentation that uses empty content-type, however there is documentation for different values of content-type, so I assume empty content-type is something that Cloud Functions cannot handle.